# How to handle Arduino returns

Tags: arduino

I feel incredibly silly for having to ask this, but how do I work with return values?

For example, I have this code:

```
int x = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int y = calc(x);
  Serial.println(y);

  delay(500);
}

int calc(int nmbr){
 int i = nmbr + 1;
 return i; 
}
```

How do I make it that x goes up? Basically, I want to see it go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc, etc
I know this is easily done with a for(), but I want to know how to work with return values, not how to create a counter.

The solution is probably very easy, and I'll facepalm when I see it, but I've been looking at my screen for the past 30 minutes and I'm completely stuck on this.

Comment: what do you mean by how to work with return values ?

Comment: well, how do I change x so it increases? Basically, x should change into the return value of calc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing `x`, you're changing another variable `nmbr`, because you're passing `x` by value, that is a copy of `x`, you could either pass it by reference, or since `x` is global you could just do this:

```
int calc() {
 return x++;
}
```

But really, you should just use a for loop :)

```
int x;
for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
  Serial.println(x);
}
```

Comment: I know, I made this little bit of code just as an example. And I knew the solution would be easy, and I am indeed facepalming right now... Thank you good sir or madam!

Answer (score 1):

Mux's answer is good. I'll add some more varieties. First, just assign the function return value back to `x`:

```
loop() {
    x = calc( x );
    Serial.println( x );
}
```

Second, use call-by-reference, where you pass a pointer to `x` instead of the value of `x`.

```
void loop() {
    int y = calc( &x );
    Serial.println( y );
}

int calc( int *nmbr ) {
    *nmbr++;
}
```

It would really do you good to read ["The C Programming Language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) to get the hang of the language and its possibilities. Good luck :-)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int y = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  y = calc(y);
  Serial.println(y);

  delay(500);
}

int calc(int nmbr){
 int i = nmbr + 1;
 return i; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring as int , you could have Declare static int .

```
#include <stdio.h>


void func() {
    static int x = 0; // x is initialized only once across three calls of func() and x will get incremented three 
                          //times after all the three calls. i.e x will be 2 finally
    printf("%d\n", x); // outputs the value of x
    x = x + 1;
}

int main() { //int argc, char *argv[] inside the main is optional in the particular program
    func(); // prints 0
    func(); // prints 1
    func(); // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```